# daggerAndroidSupport is not working when using AndroidX

Tags: android, dagger-2, androidx, android-jetifier

I have following dependencies in my gradle file :

```
gradleVersion = '3.3.0'
kotlinVersion = '1.3.11'
supportLibraryVersion = '1.1.0-alpha01'
ktxCoreVersion = '1.1.0-alpha03'
daggerVersion = '2.19'

Libs = [
            kotlin          : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${kotlinVersion}",
            appCompat       : "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${supportLibraryVersion}",
            ktxCore         : "androidx.core:core-ktx:${ktxCoreVersion}"
    ]

    Dagger = [
            dagger              : "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}",
            daggerCompiler      : "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}",
            daggerAndroid       : "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:${daggerVersion}",
            daggerAndroidSupport: "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${daggerVersion}",
            daggerProcessor     : "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${daggerVersion}"
    ]
```

For some reason `daggerAndroidSupport` is not compatible with `AndroidX`. I receive following error when I build the project:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: fragment
Affected Modules: app
```

Anyone know a solution for this?

`Addenda`:

I am using Android Studio 3.3, and here is a link to sample project : https://drive.google.com/file/d/15PsnOKfEyI91Pr350SHuN6TGuN7QCa7F/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can try using either `2.20` or `2.21` daggerVersion

Comment: I tried both versions but problem still exist.

Comment: Could you add to the question, the error generated by the dagger? and add more information of the androidx imports (fragments, activity, etc), currently I have a project with androidx and it works correctly with dagger

Comment: @JuanE.LondoñoT. which version of Android studio are you using? please take a look on `Addenda` section in my question.

Comment: in the code that you share, I do not see code that implements dagger, I only see that you add the dependencies of dagger. in the same way download the project and as it compiles without problems, to validate it would be good to add the code where you perform the dependency injection with dagger. in the following link you can see the compilation result https://imgur.com/a/LnBiMh0

Comment: But I can't build the project. For some reason it fails during build. which version of Android Studio are you using?